# Kotlin generics with heterogenous containers

Tags: kotlin, generics, heterogeneous

Suppose I have a heterogeneous map container, where keys contain type information on values:

```kotlin
interface Container<K : Container.Key<*>> {
    interface Key<V>
    
    interface Entry<K : Key<V>, V>
}
```

I want to have a `get()` function akin to

```kotlin
fun <V> get(key: Key<V>): V?
```

but also restrict this function to our type parameter `K` - The idea is that a class that implements `Container` might also have their custom key type `Container.Key<V>`, and we want the input parameter to `get()` be `Container.Key<V>` as a result.

Is this expressible in Kotlin?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible (yet).

You essentially want:

```
fun <V, TKey: K & Key<V>> get(key: TKey): V?
```

That is, `get` should take a thing that is both a `K`, and a `Key<V>`. Unfortunately, this kind of intersection type is not available yet.

Kotlin only supports intersection types of the form `T & Any`, where `T` is a nullable type parameter, to express "the non-nullable version of T".

There is a lengthy discussion [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13108) about adding better intersection type support.

So for now, you can only enforce `TKey: K & Key<V>` at runtime. Take in two parameters - a `K` and a `Key<V>`. Enforce that they are the same object.

```
// users would call this by passing the same thing twice
fun <V> get(key1: K, key2: Key<V>): V?
```

In the implementation you should check `key1 === key2`.

Note that we cannot check that a key is indeed a `Key<V>` and not `Key<SomethingElse>` at runtime, because `V` is erased. You *can* take a `KClass<V>` to work around this, but that doesn't work well if `V` is itself parameterised.

If that is fine for you, and your `Key` interface has a way to tell you if it is a `Key<V>`, given a `KClass<V>`, you can use a signature like this instead:

```
fun <V> get(key: K, clazz: KClass<V>): V?
// in the implementation, check if key is Key<V>, using members of Key<*> and clazz
```